# How to submit applications to yarn-cluster so jars in packages are also copied?

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop-yarn, emr

I'm trying to submit a spark job specifying the `spark-csv` package as a dependency:

```
spark/bin/spark-submit --packages com.databricks:spark-csv_2.10:1.0.3 --deploy-mode cluster --master yarn-cluster script.py
```

But I get the following exception (snippet)

```
15/05/05 22:23:46 INFO yarn.Client: Source and destination file systems are the same. Not copying /home/hadoop/.ivy2/jars/spark-csv_2.10.jar
Exception in thread "main" java.io.FileNotFoundException: File does not exist: hdfs://172.31.13.205:9000/home/hadoop/.ivy2/jars/spark-csv_2.10.jar
```

The `spark` cluster is installed and configured with the following script:

```
aws emr create-cluster --name sandbox --ami-version 3.6 --instance-type m3.xlarge --instance-count 3 \
    --ec2-attributes KeyName=sandbox \
    --applications Name=Hive \
    --bootstrap-actions Path=s3://support.elasticmapreduce/spark/install-spark  \
    --log-uri s3://mybucket/spark-logs \
    --steps \
    Name=SparkHistoryServer,Jar=s3://elasticmapreduce/libs/script-runner/script-runner.jar,Args=s3://support.elasticmapreduce/spark/start-history-server \
    Name=SparkConfigure,Jar=s3://elasticmapreduce/libs/script-runner/script-runner.jar,Args=[s3://support.elasticmapreduce/spark/configure-spark.bash,spark.default.parallelism=100,spark.locality.wait.rack=0]
```

This should be widely applicable to Spark developers as I imagine using EMR with Spark is not an uncommon workflow and I'm not doing anything too complex.

Here's the extended stack trace:

```
Spark assembly has been built with Hive, including Datanucleus jars on classpath
Ivy Default Cache set to: /home/hadoop/.ivy2/cache
The jars for the packages stored in: /home/hadoop/.ivy2/jars
:: loading settings :: url = jar:file:/home/hadoop/.versions/spark-1.3.0.d/lib/spark-assembly-1.3.0-hadoop2.4.0.jar!/org/apache/ivy/core/settings/ivysettings.xml
com.databricks#spark-csv_2.10 added as a dependency
:: resolving dependencies :: org.apache.spark#spark-submit-parent;1.0
    confs: [default]
    found com.databricks#spark-csv_2.10;1.0.3 in central
    found org.apache.commons#commons-csv;1.1 in central
:: resolution report :: resolve 238ms :: artifacts dl 8ms
    :: modules in use:
    com.databricks#spark-csv_2.10;1.0.3 from central in [default]
    org.apache.commons#commons-csv;1.1 from central in [default]
    ---------------------------------------------------------------------
    |                  |            modules            ||   artifacts   |
    |       conf       | number| search|dwnlded|evicted|| number|dwnlded|
    ---------------------------------------------------------------------
    |      default     |   2   |   0   |   0   |   0   ||   2   |   0   |
    ---------------------------------------------------------------------
:: retrieving :: org.apache.spark#spark-submit-parent
    confs: [default]
    0 artifacts copied, 2 already retrieved (0kB/10ms)
15/05/05 22:07:23 INFO client.RMProxy: Connecting to ResourceManager at /172.31.13.205:9022
15/05/05 22:07:23 INFO yarn.Client: Requesting a new application from cluster with 2 NodeManagers
15/05/05 22:07:23 INFO yarn.Client: Verifying our application has not requested more than the maximum memory capability of the cluster (11520 MB per container)
15/05/05 22:07:23 INFO yarn.Client: Will allocate AM container, with 896 MB memory including 384 MB overhead
15/05/05 22:07:23 INFO yarn.Client: Setting up container launch context for our AM
15/05/05 22:07:23 INFO yarn.Client: Preparing resources for our AM container
15/05/05 22:07:24 INFO yarn.Client: Uploading resource file:/home/hadoop/.versions/spark-1.3.0.d/lib/spark-assembly-1.3.0-hadoop2.4.0.jar -> hdfs://172.31.13.205:9000/user/hadoop/.sparkStaging/application_1430862769169_0005/spark-assembly-1.3.0-hadoop2.4.0.jar
15/05/05 22:07:24 INFO metrics.MetricsSaver: MetricsConfigRecord disabledInCluster: false instanceEngineCycleSec: 60 clusterEngineCycleSec: 60 disableClusterEngine: false 
15/05/05 22:07:24 INFO metrics.MetricsSaver: Created MetricsSaver j-3C91V87M8TXWD:i-e4bd8f2d:SparkSubmit:05979 period:60 /mnt/var/em/raw/i-e4bd8f2d_20150505_SparkSubmit_05979_raw.bin
15/05/05 22:07:25 INFO yarn.Client: Source and destination file systems are the same. Not copying /home/hadoop/.ivy2/jars/spark-csv_2.10.jar
Exception in thread "main" java.io.FileNotFoundException: File does not exist: hdfs://172.31.13.205:9000/home/hadoop/.ivy2/jars/spark-csv_2.10.jar
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.Hdfs.getFileStatus(Hdfs.java:129)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.AbstractFileSystem.resolvePath(AbstractFileSystem.java:460)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileContext$23.next(FileContext.java:2120)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileContext$23.next(FileContext.java:2116)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FSLinkResolver.resolve(FSLinkResolver.java:90)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileContext.resolve(FileContext.java:2116)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileContext.resolvePath(FileContext.java:591)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.Client.copyFileToRemote(Client.scala:203)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.Client$$anonfun$prepareLocalResources$4$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(Client.scala:285)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.Client$$anonfun$prepareLocalResources$4$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(Client.scala:280)
    at scala.collection.IndexedSeqOptimized$class.foreach(IndexedSeqOptimized.scala:33)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayOps$ofRef.foreach(ArrayOps.scala:108)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.Client$$anonfun$prepareLocalResources$4.apply(Client.scala:280)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.Client$$anonfun$prepareLocalResources$4.apply(Client.scala:278)
    at scala.collection.immutable.List.foreach(List.scala:318)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.Client.prepareLocalResources(Client.scala:278)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.Client.createContainerLaunchContext(Client.scala:384)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.Client.submitApplication(Client.scala:102)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.Client.run(Client.scala:619)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.Client$.main(Client.scala:647)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.Client.main(Client.scala)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.org$apache$spark$deploy$SparkSubmit$$runMain(SparkSubmit.scala:569)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.doRunMain$1(SparkSubmit.scala:166)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.submit(SparkSubmit.scala:189)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.main(SparkSubmit.scala:110)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.main(SparkSubmit.scala)
15/05/05 22:07:25 INFO metrics.MetricsSaver: Saved 3:3 records to /mnt/var/em/raw/i-e4bd8f2d_20150505_SparkSubmit_05979_raw.bin
Command exiting with ret '1'
```

Comment: Why are you using EMR? What's the advantage compared to plain EC2? There's an [official script](https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.3.1/ec2-scripts.html) for running Spark on EC2. Doesn't EMR just complicate things and cost more?

Comment: @DanielDarabos I switched to `spark-ec2` script that comes with Spark and I'm not having any issues.

Comment: @DanielDarabos There is actually a lot of difference. Mainly the uptime of the cluster. If you set up a cluster using ec2 script for around 50+ machines it takes more than 45 minutes to have them up and ready for use. EMR does this in less than half that time. Plus EMR allows you to very conveniently automate batch spark jobs. Its a pain when you need to do this with spark-ec2 script. Particularly the logging in case a task fails.

Answer (score 3):

I think this may be an Apache Spark bug, though I don't see it reported in the [Spark JIRA](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK). http://apache-spark-user-list.1001560.n3.nabble.com/Resources-not-uploaded-when-submitting-job-in-yarn-client-mode-td21516.html seems to describe the same situation, however. According to that post the issue is that in your deployment setup Spark mistakenly believes that the destination system is the same as the client system, so it foregoes the copying:

> 15/05/05 22:07:25 INFO yarn.Client: Source and destination file systems are the same. Not copying /home/hadoop/.ivy2/jars/spark-csv_2.10.jar

I'd recommend trying `--jars` instead of `--packages` (see [Submitting Applications](https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.3.1/submitting-applications.html)). If that works, please file a bug about this issue!

Comment: What is the setting to fix this ?

Comment: No idea. Did `--jars` instead of `--packages` help? A recent post at https://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/spark-user/201512.mbox/%3CCADfcUwF5xxFCsJs1ZiLf9mACiruNkLvfxJmqdGa++ovh5qN9Dw@mail.gmail.com%3E suggests maybe you just need a `core-site.xml` file.

Comment: I have already got a core-site.xml . Which I downloaded from ambari's "Download Client Config" option fro YARN service. This is the version I have copied in to my Dev machine Hadoop configs

Answer (score 0):

It seems client jar is not copied to Hadoop cluster but try to copy locally. I have also faced similar problem. I set up HADOOP_CONF_DIR property in /conf/spark-env.sh

Please refer to tutorial http://leveragebigdata.blogspot.com/2016/12/remote-run-spark-job-on-hadoop-yarn.html for reference.